# Why is phenol a solid at room temperature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, phase

The commonly cited reason is inter-molecular hydrogen bonding. But won't the hydrogen bonding in phenol be weaker than that of most alcohols because of resonance-effect? And yet, alcohols with stronger hydrogen bonding (such as ethanol, propanol, etc.) aren't solids at room temperature.

Also, if the reason behind its state is it's molecular weight, then why is benzyl alcohol a liquid at room temperature? The hydrogen bonding in benzyl alcohol is stronger (less resonance-effect) and its molecular weight is also higher.

Comment: It can also be due to $\pi$-[stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacking_(chemistry))

Comment: Benzene freezes at +5°C, cyclohexane at +7. It's a matter of efficient packing in the crystal, plus a little hydrogen bonding.